# Update mshp-file with SAGA GIS?

Tags: shapefile, fields-attributes, saga

I want to update the mshp-file of a shapefile with SAGA.

My issue is: I renamed some columns of a shapefile with SAGA (`saga_cmd table_tools 23`). For renaming I had to give SAGA the dbf-file, because it doesn't work with a shp-file. But if I now create buffers for this shapefile, the buffer has the old field names. If I delete the mshp-file, everything works. However, if possible I would like to keep the mshp-file.

Is there any way to update the mshp-file? When looking at the files in a text explorer, the dbf-file contains the new field names, but the mshp-file contains the old field names.

Comment: What's an "mshp-file"? It is unwise to manipulate the dBase-III component of a shapefile with a GIS-unaware application, since there is a high probability of corruption. It is likewise risky to use a text editor on a binary file format.

Comment: The mshp-file is one of the several files SAGA creates when it creates a shapefile. It's part of the shapefile. I thought, SAGA GIS would be aware of GIS. And it doesn't allow me to hand over the shp-file to the renaming tool since it only contains geometries...